# (discord.py) How to I make my Discord Bot resend attachments from a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What I wanted to ask here is how do I make a discord bot resend all the attachments from a message, given a specific event/situation?

Here's my code:

```
    if "ngab" in message.content.lower():
        content=message.content.lower()
        final=content.replace("ngab",":ng::ab:")
        if len(final)<=2000:
            attc = message.attachments    
            ref = message.reference
            await message.delete()        
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}: {final}', reference=ref)
        else:
            await message.reply(f"kata mas discord kepanjangan :ng::ab: {message.author.mention}")
```

Here I already saved the attachments of the message into the variable `attc`, yet I still don't know how to resend the attachments through the bot. I poked around the documentation, tried using discord.File, which requires me to save the attachments first, which would probably stutter the 8 year old cpu, then I tried this

```
            if message.attachments:
                for attachment in attc:    
                    await message.channel.send(attachment.url)
```

which works well, albeit the attachments being sent separate from the message and one by one. So how do I make the bot send it all at once?

Thanks in advance to anyone helping or just reading. Forgive me for any mistakes I made in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by all at once, each attachment you upload is its own message so regardless if you use `discord.File` or not it will be 2 different messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send more than once.
Also, users can't send more than one attachment.
So don't mind.